# Firebase | Google Sheet | App Script | How do I put the value on new row everytime the function is triggered?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, firebase-realtime-database

I have to extract the data from Firebase to the Google Sheet. I have managed to sync my Firebase data to the Google Sheet but I can't put it in a new row everytime the trigger is called in App Script.

Here's my code in App Script:

```
function getAllData() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var firebaseUrl = "firebase url";
  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);

  var dataSet = [base.getData()];
  var rows = [], data;

  for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
    data = dataSet[i];
    var in_time = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8", "HH:mm:ss");
    var in_date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8", "yyyy-MM-dd");
    rows.push([data.Tank1, data.RandomTank1, data.RandomMain, in_time, in_date]);

  }
  a=2;
  dataRange = sheet.getRange(a, 1, rows.length, 5);
  dataRange.setValues(rows);
}
```

The output is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAnZN.png)

And I want it to look like this and update the data in a new row:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1Pyd.png)

EDIT:

Thank you very much @onit for solving this for me! It worked!

Here's the screenshot of the output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuTGE.png)

Comment: I'd begin by replacing the last 2 rows with: `dataRange = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, rows.length,  rows[0].length).setValues(rows)`;

Comment: @onit How about posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the last 2 lines with:
 `dataRange = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, rows.length, rows[0].length).setValues(rows);`

**References**

[getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)

[setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: It worked!!!! Thank you very much! I want to up your answer but it seems like I can't :(

Comment: Glad to see it helped.